# Undefined index on innerJoin using queryBuilder PHP

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I try to echo column called 'employeeNumber' using queryBuilder in PHP, but whatever I do here I get "undefined index: employeeNumber' error. Here is sample of the code

```
$queryBuilder2 = $conn->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder2->select('c.customerNumber, c.customerName, e.employeeNumber')
    ->from('customers', 'c')
    ->innerJoin('c', 'employees', 'e', 'c.salesRepEmployeeNumber = e.employeeNumber');

$stmt2 = $queryBuilder2->execute();
$results2 = $stmt2->fetchAll();
foreach($results as $row)
{
    echo "Data:  {$row['customerNumber']} | {$row['customerName']} | {$row['employeeNumber']}\n";        
}
```

I assume that it is connected with innerJoin, but can't really figure it out.

Comment: use print_r($row) to see the keys (names of the fields) of the array.

Comment: I get everything from 'customers' table when I print $row, but what I really want is to access 'employees' table